# Pattern matching on tuples in Kotlin

Tags: pattern-matching, tuples, kotlin

I have the following piece of code

```kotlin
fun changeSelection(item: FileOrFolder, selected: Boolean) {
    selection = when(item) {
        is Folder -> {
            when(selected) {
                true -> selection + item
                false -> selection - item
            }
        }
        is File -> {
            when(selected) {
                true -> selection + item
                false -> selection - item
            }
        }
        else -> throw Exception("unreachable")
    }
}
```

which looks kinda cluttered for me as I got used to this in scala

```scala
def changeSelection(item: FileOrFolder, selected: Boolean) {
    (item, selected) match {
        case (item: Folder, true) => selection + item
        case (item: Folder, false) => selection - item
        case (item: File, true) => selection + item
        case (item: File, false) => selection - item
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar in Kotlin?

Comment: The logic doesn't seem to depend on the type of `item` at all. If it does, you should probably mention it or modify the code sample.

Comment: Hello, seeker! Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315468/kotlin-whenpair-is-there-any-other-way) with other possible solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, for Scala's sake, you can write:

```
fun changeSelection(item: FileOrFolder, selected: Boolean) {
    selection = when {
        item is Folder &&  selected -> selection + item
        item is Folder && !selected -> selection - item
        item is File   &&  selected -> selection + item
        item is File   && !selected -> selection - item
        else -> throw Exception()
    }
}
```

A more straight-forward version would be:

```
fun changeSelection(item: FileOrFolder, selected: Boolean) {
    selection = if(selected)
        when(item) {
            is Folder -> selection + item
            is File   -> selection + item
            else -> throw Exception()
        }
    else
        when(item) {
            is Folder -> selection - item
            is File   -> selection - item
            else -> throw Exception()
        }
}
```

But I definitely prefer:

```
operator fun Selection.plus(f: FileOrFolder) = ...
operator fun Selection.minus(f: FileOrFolder) = ...

fun changeSelection(item: FileOrFolder, selected: Boolean) {
    if(selected)
        selection += item
    else 
        selection -= item
}
```

Comment: @Yaroslav, which option did you use (out of the three above)? Just curious :D

Comment: the first one, the third is nice also