# Kotlin when(Pair<>), is there any other way?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `when` construct that wants to match on two things:

```
when (activeRequest.verb to activeRequest.resourceType) {
    GET to "all" -> allGet()
    PUT to "foo" -> fooPut()
    GET to "foo" -> fooGet()
    POST to "bar" -> barPost()
    GET to "bar" -> barGet()
    COPY to "bar" -> barCopy()
    DELETE to "bar" -> barDelete()
    else -> logMismatch()
}
```

Is using the `to` pair constructor the only way to do this? It seems an odd use of Pair (though it works). I struggled to find it, because code fragments like

```
for ((key, value) in hashMap) {
    println("$key $value)
}
```

made me thing I should be able to do something similar in the `when` code, e.g.

```
when (activeRequest.verb, activeRequest.resourceType) {
    (GET, "all") -> allGet()
    (PUT, "foo") -> fooPut()
   ...
    else -> logMismatch()
}
```

While the pair works... what if I wanted to do 3 items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in you for loop example is a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), which is basically syntactic sugar to declare references to multiple member variables of an object in one line. It doesn't go back the other way, as Kotlin doesn't have a mechanism for arbitrary tuples.

I can't really come up with a nice looking way to do this with more than two variables. The options I have on my mind are to either use an [enum](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html) that basically works as a tuple like this:

```
enum class Response(val verb: String, val type: String) {

    GET_FOO("GET", "foo"),
    ...
    INVALID("?", "?");

    companion object {
        fun from(verb: String, type: String): Response {
            for(response in values()) {
                if(response.verb == verb && response.type == type)
                    return response
            }

            return INVALID
        }
    }
}

when(Response.from(activeRequest.verb, activeRequest.resourceType)) {
    GET_FOO -> getFoo()
    ...
}
```

Or to use arrays. Unfortunately, Kotlin array equality is not by contents, so you end up with a lot of boilerplate, and `when` syntax stops looking very good. (I added an extension function to make this a little better, but I still don't love it):

```
fun Array<*>.whenCheat(vararg others: Any?): Boolean {
    return this contentEquals others
}

val array = arrayOf("GET", "foo")
when {
   array.whenCheat("GET", "foo") -> getFoo()
   ...
}
```

My suspicion is that this kind of thing would be better served by a map of responses to functions. Hopefully someone else comes by with a more clever solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use a `data class`. For example:

```
data class Response(val verb: String, val type: String, val other: Int)

// This is an example of what the functions could be... edit as needed
val all = { _: Response -> "all"}
val some = { _: Response -> "some"}
val unknown = { _: Response -> "unknown"}

val handlers = mapOf<Response, (Response) -> String>(
    Response("GET", "all", 200) to all,
    Response("GET", "some", 400) to some
    // and all your other mappings
)
```

Then, you can use that map like:

```
val myFun = handlers.getOrDefault(myResponse, unknown)
```

Answer (score 1):

> what if I wanted to do 3 items?

Use `Triple` instead of `Pair`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` with as many items as you want, if you just bundle the data in a class and override its `equals` method:

```
class Person(
        var firstName: String = "",
        var lastName: String = "",
        var age: Int = 0,
        var rate: Int = 0) {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        val otherPerson = other as Person

        return (
                firstName.equals(otherPerson.firstName) &&
                lastName.equals(otherPerson.lastName) &&
                age.equals(otherPerson.age) &&
                rate.equals(otherPerson.rate))
    }

    // just to avoid warning
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return super.hashCode()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array < String > ) {
    val p = Person("John", "Doe", 18, 2)
    when (p) {
        Person("Nick", "Doe", 18, 2) -> println("found at 1")
        Person("John", "Doe", 18, 2) -> println("found at 2")
        Person("Maria", "Doe", 18, 2) -> println("found at 3")
        else -> println("not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly where data classes excel at: automatically defining `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Exactly________